# How to add an Ink annotation to a pdf

Tags: fpdf, mpdf, fpdi

I know you can do `$pdf->annotation('test');` in mpdf, which works perfectly fine, but how do you add other types of annotations? one example is "/Subtype /Ink" on which [The annotation() function documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/annotation.html) says nothing about. I also searched for fpdf solutions because i understand that mpdf is only an extension of fpdf, but found nothing.

Comment: At least mPDF does not support other than documented annotation types.

Comment: @Finwe is there any other way to insert the raw pdf annotation structure then? doesnt have to be any ->annotation() function

Comment: Without altering mPDF code, no. You can edit the resulting PDF file.